# Is there an equivalent of arch linux's yaourt in debian?

Tags: debian, arch-linux, package-management, aptitude

I am an arch linux user using some debian machines. I am very used to using yaourt to install any and every random thing I can think of so that even random packages are version controlled on my system. Is there a similar system on debian to install unsupported packages? I have been unable to find anything similar and think it would take a long time to manually install everything.

For reference, some of the packages I am trying to install are `vimcat` and `fasd`.

Comment: I'm also struggling to figure out how to install emacs24 in debian, advice on how to do that would be helpful too. :)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install emacs24` https://packages.debian.org/sid/emacs24 Apt is the repository tool for debian distros, and works rather well overall (far better than the experiences I've had with yum). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool

Comment: @FrankThomas Thank you, so you can install packages from sid (which if I understand right is the unstable package repository, right?) with a normal debian distro? brilliant, that is pretty much what I was trying to figure out how to do. Thanks. Is that the only source for normal user packages in debian? If so then put that as an answer and I'd accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @FrankThomas Actually, sorry, that doesn't work for me, how do I set apt-get to install from packages.debian.org/sid/emacs24?

Comment: well, you set your sources in /etc/apt/sources.list. see more details here: https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList here is info on configuring to read from the unstable repos: http://www.binarytides.com/enable-testing-repo-debian/

Comment: @FrankThomas Thank you, I think the second article you link to solves my question. If you put it as an answer I'll accept it, otherwise I'll pull the relevant sources out and answer it myself, whichever you prefer.